# Play2 with Apache mod_proxy. Where can I correct route paths?

Tags: apache, playframework-2.0

I trying to use Play2 application behind the Apache web server, so in the httpd.conf I have this configuration

```
RewriteEngine On
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On

ProxyPass /webschool http://localhost:9000
ProxyPassReverse /webschool http://localhost:9000
<Proxy http://localhost:9000/*>
    Order deny,allow
    allow from all
</Proxy>
```

I can access Play2 content via `http://localhost/webschool/` url, but all assets is point to `/assets/...` instead of `/webschool/assets/...` paths. How can I correct Play2 paths and routes?

Best regards.

Comment: Finally you want to use the app in the same folder or in normal domain ?

Comment: In the same folder. I just want to "connect" play application as a folder of site. What is the difference will be if I will use app as `webschool.somesite.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play isn't aware of subfolder so considers `/` path as a root.

Use local (sub)domain instead of subfolder i.e. `http://webschool.loc/` to get paths like `http://webschool.loc/assets/...`, otherwise you will need to prefix all occurences in templates to reflect the folder part:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="/webschool@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/main.css")" rel="stylesheet" >
        <script src="/webschool@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/hello.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <a href="/webschool@routes.Application.index()">Main page...</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want/need to stay with subfolder also change your Apache config:

```
Redirect /webschool /webschool/
ProxyPass /webschool/ http://localhost:9000
ProxyPassReverse /webschool/ http://localhost:9000
```

Comment: Ok. So, probably better is to create new Apache VirtualHost and congigure it for play. Right?

Comment: Yes I do it for every project developed locally, don't forget to add the `webschool.loc` to your `hosts` file and flush DNS cache.